# The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception with VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, emgucv

I am using *EmguCV* version *2.4.9.1847* with *VS2012* and I have problems with `Emgu.CV.Capture` class. Its' throwing `"The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception."`

When I start the Capture sample I works fine , but when I try this `Capture camera = new Capture();` it's throwing the above exception. *CLR* and *OpenCV* are 64 bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely a duplicate. Search "Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274372/the-type-initializer-for-emgu-cv-cvinvoke-threw-an-exception or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503427/the-type-initializer-for-emgu-cv-cvinvoke-threw-an-exception

Comment: Actualy the solution is to copy/paste all the unmanaged .dll's from bin folder to the folder where your .exe is . This solution is not present in other posts.

Comment: Well found - put that as an answer then. You can answer your own questions :-)